append row to list if value is True
I'm trying to append any row where Ans == True to a separate list. Using below, I'm getting a type error. Ideally, there is a more efficient way, but I need to iterate row by row.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
   'Code': ['t1', 't2','t3'],
   'Ans': [True, False, True],
   'Val': [140, 145,140],
})

Trues = []

for row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Ans'] == True:
        Trues.append(row)

print(Trues)

Out:
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str


I think you meant to say if row['Ans'] == True, instead of if df['Ans'] == True.

Just df = df[df["Ans"]] to pick out the rows where it's True

@JohnGordon, apologies, mistake my end

.iterrows() returns an (index, row) tuple. Try for index, row in df.iterrows():. If you really need to iterate.

You shouldn't be appending "rows" to a list. .iterrows iterates over the "rows" as pd.Series objects, and it makes no sense to create a list of those. You should almost certainly just subset your dataframe, using the boolean column itself:
In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({
   ...:    'Code': ['t1', 't2','t3'],
   ...:    'Ans': [True, False, True],
   ...:    'Val': [140, 145,140],
   ...: })

In [4]: df_true = df[df['Ans']]

In [5]: df_true
Out[5]:
  Code   Ans  Val
0   t1  True  140
2   t3  True  140

If you must have a list, then get a list of dicts using built-in methods:
In [6]: mylist = df[df['Ans']].to_dict(orient='records')

In [7]: mylist
Out[7]:
[{'Code': 't1', 'Ans': True, 'Val': 140},
 {'Code': 't3', 'Ans': True, 'Val': 140}]

The problem with your approach is that .iterrows iterates over index, row pairs. So just ignore the first item of the pair when you iterate by assigning it to the conventional throw-away variable _:
In [8]: [row for _, row in df.iterrows() if row['Ans']]
Out[8]:
[Code      t1
 Ans     True
 Val      140
 Name: 0, dtype: object,
 Code      t3
 Ans     True
 Val      140
 Name: 2, dtype: object]

